# Sum of array element : invalid literal for int() with base 10:

Tags: python

My code is :

```
arr = []
n  = int(input("Enter the number of element: "))
for i in range(n):
    element = int(input("Enter elements : "))
    arr.append(element)
print(arr)
def arr_sum(arr):
    ans = sum(arr)
    return ans
print(arr_sum(arr))
```

Error :

```
element = int(input("Enter elements : "))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '86 77 15 93 35 86 92 49 21 62 27 90 59 63 26 40 26 72 36 11 68 67 29 82 30 62 23 67 35 29 2 22 58 69 67 93 56 11 42 29 73 21 19 84 37 98 24 15 70 13 26 91 80 56 73 62 70 96 81 5 25 84 27 36 5 46 29 1
```

What can I do to fix this problem?

Comment: _What can I do to fix this problem?_ Have you done any debugging? What do you understand from that error message?

Answer (score 0):

Unless, I am missing some nuance, the code should work as-is. You are not supposed to enter all the elements at once. Instead, type them one at a time with a return after each entry.

```
Enter the number of element: >? 2
Enter elements : >? 1
Enter elements : >? 2
[1, 2]
3
```